# why pip freeze returns some "gibberish" instead of package==VERSION?

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

Here is what I did:

```
❯ pip freeze
aiohttp @ file:///Users/aiven/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/50/32/0b/b64b02b6cefa4c089d84ab9edf6f0d960ca26cfbe57fe0e693a00912da/aiohttp-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl
async-timeout @ file:///Users/aiven/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/0d/5d/3e/630122e534c1b25e36c3142597c4b0b2e9d3f2e0a9cea9f10ac219f9a7/async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
attrs @ file:///Users/aiven/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/7f/e7/44/32ca3c400bb4d8a2f1a91d1d3f22bbaee2f4727a037aad898fbf5d36ce/attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
chardet @ file:///Users/aiven/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/c2/02/35/0d93b80c730b360c5e3d9bdc1b8d1929dbd784ffa8e3db025c14c045e4/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
...
```

Version of pip:

```
❯ pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/aiven/projects/foobar/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I expected something like this:

```
> pip freeze
foo==1.1.1
bar==0.2.1
```

`pip freeze -h` wasn't very helpful...

For context: I installed packages into virtualenv using `poetry`.

Comment: Will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960199/pip-freeze-does-not-show-all-installed-packages/45207675

Comment: How did you run pip exactly? Since Poetry will create and invoke environments as needed when you run commands through it, you'll have to run `poetry run pip freeze` to see the correct environment…?!

Comment: If you could'nt solve it, you can still get the versions and package names **for now** by looking at the end of each line from the output

Comment: `poetry run pip freeze` returned the same stuff. This is the first time I encounter this behaviour...

Comment: Probably poetry is to blame (and it's caching magic). `pip freeze --all` returned some packages with normal version instead of a pointer to wheel.

Comment: For `requirements.txt` file generation I can use `poetry export`, so everything is fine now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to come from the changes to support [PEP 610](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0610/). In particular refer to the [Freezing an environment section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0610/#freezing-an-environment). The notion of what "freezing" entails has been expanded to include preserving direct url sources for packages that were installed with direct origins.

Poetry, with `1.1.0` has introduced a [new installer](https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1-1-0.html#brand-new-installer) that now handles discovery and download of artifacts for dependencies. This is different to the behaviour in `1.0.10` which simply let `pip` handle discover and download of required artifacts (wheels). This means that, now packages are installed using direct URL origins. This causes `pip freeze` to use direct reference format as specified in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) (eg: `package @ file://../package.whl`). For those interested, the url in question will be saved in `<package>-<version>.dist-info/direct_url.json` in the virtual env's site directory.

You can get the old format output (not sure if this will change in the future), using the following command.

```
pip --disable-pip-version-check list --format=freeze
```

Comment: Less verbose and easier to remember is `pip list --format=freeze`. See [pip/Issue#8176](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8176)