# My pip doesn't give me anything when I try pip freeze

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pip, discord.py

I have already installed hikari from pip and it works fine but just gives me blank when I try and use pip freeze also it's like my system doesn't recognize that I have installed hikari

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960199/pip-freeze-does-not-show-all-installed-packages

Comment: You need to at least tell us what command you're running and what output/error you get, otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and you installed module in one Python but now you use `pip` which shows modules in other Python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple environments. The environment where pip is installed is different from the one you are using.

Use shortcuts "Ctrl+shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to switch the python interpreter.